# how to properly start a node server in upstart so that apn will work

Tags: linux, node.js, upstart, apn-node

When I run my server from the command line via `node server.js` it runs differently (specifically the push notifications work) than when i start it with an upstart script. How should I modify my upstart script to solve this problem?

Here's an example server where the push fails in upstart vs succeeding in the commandline

```
var apn = require('apn');
var options = {
  passphrase:'certpassphrase'
};
var err = null;
var apnConnection = new apn.Connection(options);

apnConnection.on('error', function(error){
  console.log("apscallback", 1, error);
});

apnConnection.on('transmitted', function(notification){
  console.log("apscallback", 2);
  console.log(notification);
});

apnConnection.on('timeout', function(){
  console.log("apscallback", 3);
});

apnConnection.on('connected', function(){
  console.log("apscallback", 4);
});

apnConnection.on('disconnected', function(){
  console.log("apscallback", 5);
});

apnConnection.on('socketError', function(error){
  console.log("apscallback", 6, error);
});

apnConnection.on('transmissionError', function(errorCode, notification){
  console.log("apscallback", 7, errorCode);
});

apnConnection.on('cacheTooSmall', function(difference){
  console.log("apscallback", 8);
});

function sendTestNotification() {
  var deviceToken = 'mydevicetoken';
  var myDevice = new apn.Device(deviceToken);
    var note = new apn.Notification();

    note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60; // Expires 1 hour from now.
    // note.badge = 3;
    // note.sound = "ping.aiff";
    // note.alert = "\uD83D\uDCE7 \u2709 You have a new message";
    note.payload = {'message': 'somemessage', 'requester': 7};
    apnConnection.pushNotification(note, myDevice);
}

sendTestNotification();


http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:', port);
});
```

and here's what my upstart script looks like:

```
#!upstart
description "My Server"

start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

# Automatically Respawn:
respawn
respawn limit 99 5

env NODE_ENV=production
chdir /home/user/my-server/
exec node /home/user/my-server/server.js >> /var/log/my-server.log 2>&1
```

The error I get is:

```
...
apscallback 4
apscallback 5
apscallback 1 [Error: Socket unusable after connection. Hint: You may be using a certificate for the wrong environment]
... (REPEATS)
```

Comment: Have you tried with Forever? https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever

Comment: I installed forever.js and then did `forever start server.js` and this seemed to solve my problem. Not sure (still curious) why it doesn't work with upstart, but i just need it to work, so for now i'm on "forever".  Thanks @Qualcuno

Comment: Forever doesn't protect against the server powering off(many providers automatically power back on). I'd still say upstart/init.d are better options, because they start your app on system boot. Best option would be to start your app with forever using upstart.

Comment: @tsturzl you can use both: init.d/upstart to launch the app on startup, and forever to keep it alive. Or just use something like Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did set `env NODE_ENV=production` in your upstart script (by default if this is not set APN will go against the test/sandbox environment if that variable is not set). So this will go against the production APN. Do you have the right certificate in place to do that (certificate for sandbox and production are different)?

Answer (score 0):

You're upstart script is likely defaulting to root. Perhaps root doesn't have the proper certificate in its keyring. Try setting the user implicitly in your upstart script.

You should be able to set the user with `setuid <username>`